# XCode project cannot run app on IOS <7 when empty .xib is added

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have inherited a XCode project. It contains some .xibs. I can run the app on an IOS 5 iPad just fine until I open one of the .xibs. It is then converted to a new format and then I cannot start the app anymore. The same happens when I add an empty .xib

What could be wrong with my project?

Comment: Uh! I think I found the solution! When I set "Opens in" to "Xcode 4.6" the problem disappears. It seems that the format Xcode 5.0 produces code that does not run on IOS < 7. Why is that?

Comment: And especially annoying is that IOS 6/7 Deltas are ignored when I select Xcode 4.6

Answer (score 0):

If you have added .xib file with new xcode than you can't run the project with lower version of xcodes, Because the lower xcode versions can't parse the xib files.

Comment: I have only one version: 5.0.2. With this version I add the empty file. Before adding I can launch the app, afterwards not

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the files as compatible with earlier versions of iOS.

In the properties of the file, you need to make sure that the 'Builds for' option is set to the appropriate deployment target e.g. `iOS 5.0 and Later`. That will allow them to run on the older version of iOS. Additionally, if you want to retain compatibility with an older version of iOS, you should change the 'Opens in' option.

[image: Image of drop down].

Comment: I have specified "Project Deployment Target (4.3)"

Comment: The other item is the 'Opens in' - I'd mark that for an earlier release as well, in case that's introduced an incompatibility. I would need to search for an iOS 5 device at this point in order to bring any more illumination to the issue

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do when you cannot install your app in the simulator:

- Uninstall the app in the simulator
- Try again

When you switch to Opens in Xcode 5.0 for some reason you get an error updating an existing app in the simulator.